# How to convert basic POJO to Hal Representation

Tags: json, hal

Hello I am trying to use HalBuilder to convert a simple Pojo to a Hal Represenation. I find the documentation "extremely" poor and the method names are very abstract and cryptic.

I just want to pass a POJO to a method and have it return a Representation Object with a link.

That's it - can anyone help?